# Moving structure data in C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

Lets say I have the following structure in C

```
typedef struct
{
    int field1;
    char field2[16];
} MYSTRUCT;
```

Now I have a C routine that is called with a pointer to MYSTRUCT and I need to populate the structure, e.g.,

```
int MyCall(MYSTRUCT *ms)
{
    char *hello = "hello world";
    int hlen = strlen(hello);
    ms->field1 = hlen;
    strcpy_s(ms->field2,16,hello);
    return(hlen);
}
```

How would I write MyCall in C#?  I have tried this in Visual Studio 2010:

```
...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct MYSTRUCT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    UInt32 field1;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    string field2;
}

public int MyProc(ref MYSTRUCT ms)
{
    string hello = "hello world";
    int hlen = hello.Length;
    Marshal.Copy(hello, ms.field2, 0, hlen); // doesn't work
    Array.Copy(hello, ms.field2, hlen);      // doesn't work
    // tried a number of other ways with no luck
    // ms.field2 is not a resolved reference
    return(hlen);
}
```

Thanks for any tips on the right way to do this.

Comment: `ms.field2=hello;`, but you probably looking for something else. Showing code that calls `MyProc` maybe useful...

Comment: I also noticed that your strucute in C is of type int and not unsigned int, so in C# you might want to make your data type Int32 instead of UInt32

Comment: secondly if you are porting your program over to C# you don't have to use a structure layout, and if you are going to pass in a structure by reference you might as well make it a class since it passes by reference. Then you can just assign your values as you need. Now if your function is being exported to a dynamic library then you are doing good by using a structured layout.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special with Marshal or Array copy while you are working with it in C#. After you are done working with the struct and need to send it back to an unmanaged method, just pass it into the p/invoked call and the built in Marshalling will do all the work. Same with returning the structure from a p/invoked method - .NET will do the marshalling work for you if you define the structure properly.

Comment: Unless I'm completely off the ball here and you aren't marshalling between native code at all...which I assumed you were doing with all your marshalling stuff...in which case, just use it like you would use any other class in C# :)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the StructLayout.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct MYSTRUCT
{
    public UInt32 field1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string field2;
}
```

Since, you're passing as a reference, have you tried setting it as:

```
public int MyProc(ref MYSTRUCT ms)
{
    string hello = "hello world";
    ms.field2 = hello;
    return hello.Length;
}
```

When using the `ref` keyword, you'll call `MyProc` like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = new MYSTRUCT();
    Console.WriteLine(MyProc(ref s)); // you must use "ref" when passing an argument
    Console.WriteLine(s.field2);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although appaprently I have to specify "public string field2" even though MYSTRUCT is public. Otherwise it is inaccessible due to protection level.

Comment: I am getting closer, but it does not seem to like the "ref MYSTRUCT". I assume that is telling C# that it is receiving a pointer to a structure, is that correct? If not, what is the proper way to declare it?

Comment: @Neilw, yes the "ref" keyword is essential a pointer to the struct. How are you calling MyProf? are you getting any errors?